# API csv Import GUI with Formprocessor fails with smarty errors

Tags: api, import, csv, form-processor

I created a rather complicated form processor which works (through api), but when I tried to clone it (rename it to create so csv api picks it up) and tried to do the csv import.

I get the following error for each row (in the download errors)

```
Error with entity "create"! (Action Donor info failed. Caused by PHP Error 256 at /var/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php:1100: Smarty error: [in evaluated template line 1]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'n' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 585))
```

When I tried it with the same data using just formprocessor API it works, but through CSV API Import GUI it doesn't.

How would I go around debugging this. Or should I even bother? I mean it might be easier script API calls.
I always thought CSV API and Form processor would be a powerful combo.

Answer (score 1):

CSV Import and Form Processor IS a powerful combo!  Check out the [advimportformprocessor](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/advimportformprocessor) extension.

Note that this combines the "advimport" extension rather than the CSV API GUI extension with Form Processor.  It's overall better, but some work on advimport's rough edges would improve the UX.

Also note that Form Processor is pretty slow, so imports using this technique should account for that.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that project. It seems exciting. I am amazed at how quickly the functionalities keep expanding when it comes to Civi. I will try it out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @Marko I will be presenting on this on February 26th in the CiviCRM campfire chat - see https://civicrm.org/blog.  I will also be presenting my integration between Form Processor and Inlay, which lets you create remote forms that submit to Form Processor without writing code.

Comment: I tried it with the advimport and I get the same error. I still need to debug it somehow, but I have no idea how smarty fits into this.